# MS Sql query to Hibernate HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, jpql

How could I transform the following sql to HQL

```
select max(id) from mytable where id in (select top 10 id from mytable where mycolumn-value = 1234 order by id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do exactly a JPQL equivalent, because it's not possible to use `top` (or `limit`, `rownum`... each database use one different) in a subquery using JPQL.

But you use something like this:

```
select max(mt.id) from mytable mt where mt.id in 
   (select mt2.id from mytable mt2 where mt2.mycolumn-value = 1234 order by mt2.id)
```

This query ignore the top part on subquery, it will not affect the expected result.

Comment: I dont think the above query will yield my expected results as it looks like it would essentially just return the max(id) for a given mycolumn-value and not the id at a given count.

Comment: @Chris, but the query above not return the same result as your query?

Comment: Oh, i see now :) Thank you for that.